# Deploying laravel on azure app service with deploy.cmd [Windows Machine]

Tags: azure, batch-file, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am using Kudu for deployment of my application in azure app service.

By default, kudu only runs composer install in my laravel application, but i also need to run some additional npm scripts for my website to work.

I have tried to download a default deploy.cmd script using this url format as stated in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-php-mysql-app#deploy-to-azure): `https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deploymentscript`
but i get an error that says: `{"Message":"Operation only supported if not using a custom deployment script"}`

for my next solution, i downloaded kuduscript cli globally in my local windows machine to generate a default deploy.cmd in my project's root directory but i also get an error that says:
`error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\kuduscript\lib\templates\deploy.batch.php.template'`

Then i found this deploy.cmd template for php applications in :
[kudu repository](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu-deployment-scripts/blob/master/scripts/deploy-php.cmd)

upon testing it in my deployment it caused these errors:

```
Command: bash deploy.cmd
deploy.cmd: line 1: @if: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 3: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 4: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 5: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 6: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 8: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 9: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 11: ::: command not found
deploy.cmd: line 12: nul: Permission denied
deploy.cmd: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
deploy.cmd: line 13: `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ('
deploy.cmd: line 1: @if: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 3: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 4: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 5: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 6: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 8: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 9: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 11: ::: command not found\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 12: nul: Permission denied\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('\r\ndeploy.cmd: line 13: `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ('\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\85.11024.4154\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd bash deploy.cmd
```

Im already out of options.

Laravel version: 5.8

Runtime Stack: Php 7.2